# Rx buffer overwrites Tx buffer in spidev xfer2

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, python

I'm setting up a comms link between an STM32F407 MCU and the Pi3B+. The code shown below works but when the data is printed out, it looks like the RX buffer overwrites the TX one. How do I stop that? The console output is shown below the code.

```
import spidev
from time import sleep
from tabulate import tabulate  # pip3 install tabulate

ARRAY_SIZE = 56

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)
spi.mode = 0
spi.max_speed_hz = 10000000
spi.bits_per_word = 8

tx1 = [0xCA, 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff,
       0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
       0x00]

# Do an SPI transaction
# rx1 is the receive buffer
rx1 = spi.xfer2(tx1)

# Print the RX and TX arrays
headers = ['array #', 'TX', 'RX']
idx = range(0, ARRAY_SIZE, 1)
table = zip(idx, tx1, rx1)

print(tabulate(table, headers=headers))

# close the SPI port
spi.close()
```

The console output looks like this,

```
  array #    TX    RX
---------  ----  ----
        0     0     0
        1     0     0
        2     0     0
        3     0     0
        4     0     0
        5     0     0
        6     0     0
        7     0     0
        8     0     0
        9     0     0
       10     0     0
       11     0     0
       12     0     0
       13     0     0
       14     0     0
       15     0     0
       16     0     0
       17     0     0
       18     0     0
       19     0     0
       20     0     0
       21     0     0
       22     0     0
       23     0     0
       24     0     0
       25     0     0
       26     0     0
       27     0     0
       28     0     0
       29   254   254
       30   255   255
       31   134   134
       32   254   254
       33   204   204
       34   254   254
       35   253   253
       36     0     0
       37     0     0
       38     0     0
       39     0     0
       40     0     0
       41     0     0
       42     0     0
       43     0     0
       44     0     0
       45     0     0
       46     0     0
       47    54    54
       48    84    84
       49    52    52
       50   108   108
       51     0     0
       52     0     0
       53     0     0
       54     0     0
       55     0     *0
```

**EDIT**: [Solved here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/122464/rx-buffer-overwrites-tx-buffer-in-spidev-xfer2). Didn't make much headway with `spidev` but was guided on how to use an alternative library.

Comment: The [RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) might be a better home for this question, but imo the behavior you're seeing might be 'by design'.

Comment: You need to give more detail about your setup, what are you sending to, how did you connect it, and so forth.

Comment: A standard 4-wire setup really. The Pi is the master. SPI clock is set to 10MHz on the Pi. 8-bit word length on both ends. A braided cable connects the Pi and the MCU SPI ports.